# Score resetting after restart

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a clicker game. When I restart the game it shows the old score but when I click again it restarts the score to 0. I think it is pulling the information from my global variable and not from my NSUserdefaults and I do not know why.

```
var clickerBTN: UIButton!
var scoreLbl: UILabel!
var Score = NSInteger()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  if (ScoreDefault.valueForKey("Score") != nil)
        {
        var Score = ScoreDefault.valueForKey("Score") as! NSInteger!
        }
    var Score = ScoreDefault.valueForKey("Score") as! NSInteger!
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()

    scoreLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 200,height: 90))
    scoreLbl.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width*0.5, y: view.frame.size.height*0.10)
    scoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Score : %i", Score) as String
    scoreLbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    scoreLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let clickerImage = UIImage(named: "PLACEHOLDER")
    clickerBTN = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 350))
    clickerBTN.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width*0.5, y: view.frame.size.height*0.50)
    clickerBTN.addTarget(self, action: Selector("click"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    clickerBTN.setImage(clickerImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.view?.addSubview(clickerBTN)
    self.view?.addSubview(scoreLbl)
}
```

My click func

```
func click(){

    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()
    Score++
    scoreLbl.text = NSString(format: "Score : %i", Score) as String

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was just a stupid syntax error. When I called score in the "didMoveToView" I had to remove the "var" before hand because I was canceling out the global variable when I clicked the button.